# Correct typing for numpy array with Drake expressions

Tags: numpy, python-typing, drake

I making a numpy array of Drake expressions, and I am trying to type hint them correctly. This is what I am currently doing:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt
import pydrake.symbolic

def some_function(expr: pydrake.symbolic.expression) -> npt.NDArray[pydrake.symbolic.expression]:
   return np.array([expr])
```

where I am using type hints as above. However, I am getting the following error message:

```
Could not specialize type "NDArray[ScalarType@NDArray]"
Type "Expression" cannot be assigned to type "generic"
"Expression" is incompatible with "generic"
```

The same error message shows for different Drake objects like `pydrake.symbolic.Formula` etc.

For the record, I know I can use `npt.ArrayLike` instead of `npt.NDArray[...]`, and this does not throw an error. However, I would like to find a solution that shows explicitly what the contents of the numpy arrays will be.

Comment: You may need to use `dtype=object` for the type annotation, as that is how pydrake currently communicates arrays of `AutoDiffXd` and `Expression`: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/v1.11.0/bindings/pydrake/test/autodiffutils_test.py#L91-L95. I'm not a very avid user of type annotations (beyond `dataclasses`), so I don't know exact spelling unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The error message is generated by the part `npt.NDArray[sym.Expression]`. If I change this to `npt.NDArray[object]` I still get the same error, however at this point this is no longer specific to Drake. By looking at the [documentation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/typing.html#numpy.typing.NDArray) for `npt.NDArray` it seems that the type parameter must be of the type `ScalarType`, which I assume neither `object` or drake expressions are, so using `npt.NDArray` may not be the right way to go. I will keep looking for a solution!

Comment: Briefly tried it out on my side, I got `NDArray[object]` and `NDArray[Expression]` to work; see [this directory](https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/tree/5e3b73595b38a0f378f41da6119455820af56b96/drake_stuff/numpy_typing_object). Maybe you need a newer NumPy version? (see [frozen reqs file for my repro](https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/blob/5e3b73595b38a0f378f41da6119455820af56b96/drake_stuff/numpy_typing_object/requirements.freeze.txt#L15))

Comment: Yes you're right, that doesn't throw a runtime error. However my LSP (Pyright) is still giving an error for NDArray[Expression]. So to be clear, yes, my code is running fine with the example above, but the static type checking is not happy with the solution

Comment: Is it something that you can concretely reproduce the full error from, e.g., calling the corresponding CLI linting script from Pyright on the offending code, then posting basically all instructions to repro it (as I had done)?